File not found error in java even tho the file is in correct folder
file not found error 
the output is not getting while compiling but when i run from the button run from the program it runs and successful but can't compile while javac conditionals.java i get these error , many times also at many porblems . ......................................................................................................................................................

For future reference, images of text are not well received here.

package x; means that you need to compile the project from a root folder relative to a proper structure of your classes. The fact that you have the class inside a package needs you to also structure these classes in proper folder hierarchies.
A good example would be:
root [Folder]
    - conditionals [Folder]
        - conditionals.java

Inside the root folder, you can now run:
javac conditionals/conditionals.java

